# Returning list of different results that are created recursively in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, return

Lately I've been working with some recursive problems in Python where I have to generate a list of possible configurations (i.e list of permutations of a given string, list of substrings, etc..) using recursion. I'm having a very hard time in finding the best practice and also in understanding how to manage this sort of variable in recursion.

I'll give the example of the [generate binary trees](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-possible-full-binary-trees/) problem. I more-or-less know what I have to implement in the recursion:

1. If n=1, return just one node.
2. If n=3, return the only possible binary tree.
3. For n>3, crate one node and then explore the possibilities: left node is childless, right node is childless, neither node is childless. Explore these possibilites recursively.

Now the thing I'm having the most trouble visualising is how exactly I am going to arrive to the list of trees. Currently the practice I do is pass along a list in the function call (as an argument) and the function would return this list, but then the problem is in case 3 when calling the recursive function to explore the possibilites for the nodes it would be returning a list and not appending nodes to a tree that I am building. When I picture the recursion tree in my head I imagine a "tree" variable that is unique to each of the tree leaves, and these trees are added to a list which is returned by the "root" (i.e first) call. But I don't know if that is possible. I thought of a global list and the recursive function not returning anything (just appending to it) but the problem I believe is that at each call the function would receive a copy of the variable.

How can I deal with generating combinations and returning lists of configurations in these cases in recursion? While I gave an example, the more general the answer the better. I would also like to know if there is a "best practice" when it comes to that.

Comment: "Currently the practice I do is pass along a list in the function call (as an argument) and the function would return this list," Well, *what does the list represent*? What do the individual elements represent? What is the actual strategy?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. This question would be better if it were more concrete. Including actual code is good, but it also works to just explain *how* you intend to use the list in your code. I don't know what you mean by "the recursion tree". We also generally don't deal in questions about "best practice".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks. Could you elaborate on what would be considered "more concrete?" I didn't add code because that would render the question too specific. A recursion tree is presented here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html

Comment: @KarlKnechtel answering your questions in the first comment: The list would represent the possible configurations (permutations for instance) on in the question example the possible binary trees. If I am for instance to return the root of every possible binary tree, I would be returning a list of root nodes.

Comment: Re the trees: I guess they just mean drawing out all the calls that occur over the duration of the recursive algorithm; but that page seems more oriented towards determining the big-O complexity of algorithms rather than figuring out how to write them.

Comment: "I didn't add code because that would render the question too specific." You can certainly ask a general question motivated by a specific example. The code just makes it easier to understand your thought process. It seems clear that you're looking for a *technique* here; that can be a bit iffy on Stack Overflow, but this one is within what I think can be answered well, so I gave it a shot.

Comment: Yes, what you described is what they mean and it is what I meant by "recursion tree", it's what is written in the article. Yes, they use it for big-O in that specific case but it can be applied generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently the practice I do is pass along a list in the function call (as an argument) and the function would return this list

This is not the purest way to attack a recursive problem. It would be better if you can make the recursive function such that it solves the sub problem without an extra parameter variable that it must use. So the recursive function should just return a result *as if* it was the only call that was ever made (by the testing framework). So in the example, that recursive call should *return* a list with trees.

Alternatively the recursive function could be a sub-function that doesn't return a list, but yields the individual values (in this case: trees). The caller can then decide whether to pack that into a list or not. This is more pythonic.

As to the example problem, it is also important to identify some invariants. For instance, it is clear that there are no solutions when *n* is even. As to recursive aspect: once you have decided to create a root, then both its left and right sided subtree will have an odd number of nodes. Of course, this is an observation that is specific to this problem, but it is important to look for such problem properties.

Finally, it is equally important to see if the same sub problems can reoccur multiple times. This surely is the case in the example problem: for instance, the left subtree may sometimes have the same number of nodes as the right subtree. In such cases memoization will improve efficiency (dynamic programming).

When the recursive function returns a list, the caller can then *iterate* that list to retrieve its elements (trees in the example), and use them to build an extended result that satisfies the caller's task. In the example case that means that the tree taken from the recursively retrieved list, is appended as a child to a new root. Then this new tree is appended to a *new* list (not related to the one returned from the recursive call). This new list will in many cases be longer, although this depends on the type of problem.

To further illustrate the way to tackle these problems, here is a solution for the example problem: one which uses the main function for the recursive calls, and using memoization:

```
class Solution:
    memo = { 1: [TreeNode()] }
    
    def allPossibleFBT(self, n: int) -> List[Optional[TreeNode]]:
        # If we didn't solve this problem before...
        if n not in self.memo:
            # Create a list for storing the results (the trees)
            results = []
            # Before creating any root node, 
            #    decide the size of the left subtree.
            #    It must be odd
            for num_left in range(1, n, 2):
                # Make the recursive call to get all shapes of the
                # left subtree
                left_shapes = self.allPossibleFBT(num_left)
                # The remainder of the nodes must be in the right subtree
                num_right = n - 1 - num_left  # The root also counts as 1
                right_shapes = self.allPossibleFBT(num_right)
                # Now iterate the results we got from recursion and 
                #    combine them in all possible ways to create new trees
                for left in left_shapes:
                    for right in right_shapes:
                        # We have a combination. Now create a new tree from it
                        # by putting a root node on top of the two subtrees:
                        tree = TreeNode(0, left, right)
                        # Append this possible shape to our results
                        results.append(tree)
            # All done. Save this for later re-use
            self.memo[n] = results
        return self.memo[n]
```

This code can be made more compact using list comprehension, but it may make the code less readable.

Comment: I know about memoization and the odd-even properties of this problem but this is not what my question is about. What I am having trouble understanding is how to write the return statements. For instance consider that n=5, and I have to return a list of nodes. I call the function with n=3 for each child node. This would return a list of solutions for n=3, but I need the actual nodes if I am building a tree. As for the code without any explanation I find it very hard to understand.

Comment: OK, I will extend my answer and focus on what you mention in your comment. Hold on.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if this answers your doubts.

Comment: You were efficient and helpful, I understand it better now thanks. Iterating over the results is an insight I didn't have before, but makes much more sense than passing a list and appending to it.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand where you got stuck. It comes across to me like you said you wanted a general answer, but then got upset that I didn't write code for you based on your description of a specific problem. "This would return a list of solutions for n=3, but I need the actual nodes if I am building a tree."... "Iterating over the results is an insight I didn't have before" Are you *really* saying the sticking point is that it *didn't occur to you* that, given a list of subtrees, you could get the subtrees by iterating over the list?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If that was evident to you there is nothing I can say, it didn't occur to me in other problems and it didn't occur in this one. I was stuck with overall sharing of variables and what to return at each recursive call, not with how to build a recursive function. trincot answered my question better and that is why I verified it. On top of that I do not understand the point of the comment you wrote or its objective.

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing of variables"? How is "what to return at each recursive call" different from what I explained? How is "how to build a recursive function" not the topic?

Comment: Anyway, memoization is more easily accomplished using the `functools` standard library, which directly provides a `cache` (in 3.9+; in older versions, `lru_cache` can be adapted to the task simply) decorator.

Answer (score -2):

Don't pass information into the recursive calls, unless they need that information to compute their local result. It's much easier to reason about recursion when you write without side effects. So instead of having the recursive call put its own results into a list, write the code so that the results from the recursive calls are used to create the return value.

Let's take a trivial example, converting a simple loop to recursion, and using it to accumulate a sequence of increasing integers.

```
def recursive_range(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return recursive_range(n - 1) + [n]
```

We are using functions in the natural way: we put information in with the arguments, and *get information out* using the *return value* (rather than mutation of the parameters).

In your case:

> Now the thing I'm having the most trouble visualising is how exactly I am going to arrive to the list of trees.

So you know that you want to return a *list of trees* at the end of the process. So the natural way to proceed, is that you expect each recursive call to do that, too.

> How can I deal with generating combinations and returning lists of configurations in these cases in recursion? While I gave an example, the more general the answer the better.

The recursive calls return their lists of results for the sub-problems. You use those results to create the list of results for the current problem.

You *don't need to think* about how recursion is implemented in order to write recursive algorithms. You don't need to think about the call stack. You *do* need to think about two things:

- What are the base cases?
- How does the problem break down recursively? (Alternately: *why* is recursion a good fit for this problem?)

The thing is, recursion is *not special*. Making the recursive call is *just like* calling *any other function* that would happen to give you the correct answer for the sub-problem. So all you need to do is understand how solving the sub-problems helps you to solve the current one.

Comment: I don't really see how this is answering my question, I'm reading more a guide on how to implement recursion from scratch. You mention knowing what are the base cases and how to break down the problem when I've stated both in my question. Maybe my question wasn't very clear but the  recursion itself 'algorithmically' I can understand, what I'm having trouble with is the Python implementation with the return statements. I'll add code to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: "what I'm having trouble with is the Python implementation with the return statements" I don't understand how there is confusion. You write some logic that takes in the values from the recursive calls and computes a value; then you `return` that value. You *said* that "the more general the answer the better". It isn't possible to be any less vague without also being more specific. The details of how to put the results together are dictated by the exact problem you're solving.

Comment: But maybe you understand now what I mean about the concreteness of the problem?